# Multiple assocations with same base mapper

Tags: java, mybatis

I had a base resultMap for version information defined like this:

```
   <resultMap id="VersionedEntityMapper" type="org.chu.wit4h.db.AbstractVersionedEntity">
      <result property="version" column="version"/>
      <result property="lastModified" column="lastModified"/>
      <result property="lastModifier" column="lastModifier"/>
   </resultMap>
```

Then a few entity mappers extending it:

```
   <resultMap id="Entity1Mapper" type="org.Entity1" extends="VersionedEntityMapper">
      <result property="name" column="name" />
      <result property="firstName" column="firstName" />
   </resultMap>

   <resultMap id="Entity2Mapper" type="org.Entity2" extends="VersionedEntityMapper">
      <result property="room" column="room"/>
   </resultMap>
```

Everything worked fine until i did:

```
   <resultMap id="Entity3Mapper" type="org.Entity3">
      <id property="id" column="id" />
      <association property="info" javaType="org.Entity1" resultMap="Entity1Mapper"/>
      <association property="location" javaType="org.Entity2" resultMap="Entity2Mapper"/>
   </resultMap>
```

So, the column names version, lastModified and lastModifier conflict.
I can alias them in the SQL statement but how could I pass the prefix to the inner mapper?

Comment: Have you tried using `columnPrefix` attribute on `association` element? Doesn't it work for you? What error do you get if it doesn't?

Comment: No, I missed that one! Indeed, it solves the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use existing `resultMap` to map the associated entity you need to add some prefix to all the columns of the associated entity in the result and specify that prefix via `columnPrefix` attribute.

In the above example the fields for `Entity1` should be named like `entity1_name, entity1_first_name, entity1_version` etc. in the query that select `Entity3`.

The mapping should be modified:

```
<resultMap id="Entity3Mapper" type="org.Entity3">
   <id property="id" column="id" />
   <association property="info" javaType="org.Entity1" resultMap="Entity1Mapper"
       columnPrefix="entity1"/>
   ...
</resultMap>
```